# SerializationException in posting new Records via Dynamodb Proxy Service in API

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am getting

```
"__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#SerializationException"
```

as a reply in postman & in test console in API Gateway

Trying to post a record directly to dynamodb using API Proxy Services..
I am referring this AWS Article - https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/using-amazon-api-gateway-as-a-proxy-for-dynamodb/

Here's my Mapping

```
{ 
    "TableName": "TableNameGoesHere",
    "Item": {
    "id" : "$context.requestId"
    "eventName" : "$input.path('$.eventName')",
    "timestamp" : $input.path('$.timestamp'),
    "answers": "$util.parseJson($input.path('$.answers'))"
    }
}
```

Update:
I did as asked ... and it worked but now if I try to add a Array of JSON Objects it gives me the above same error - here's what I am trying to do now. Please help - Couldnt find anything on google as well

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{ 
    "TableName": "Answer",
    "Item": {
    "id": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
            },
    "eventName": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.eventName')"
            },
    "timestamp" : {
            "N": "$input.path('$.timestamp')"
            },
    "answers": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.answers')"
            },
    "Line": {
    "S" : "[
#foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Line)
    {
      "questionID" : "$elem.questionID",
      "answer" : "$elem.answer"
    }#if($foreach.hasNext),#end

#end
  ]" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> To address the challenge of having **Array of Objects** as part of the payload.

**For Request Payload**

```
{
    "emailId": "v@a.com",
    "responses": [
        {
            "question": "q1",
            "answer": "a1"
        },
        {
            "question": "q2",
            "answer": "a2"
        }
    ]
}
```

**Template would be**

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
    "TableName": "Customers",
    "Item": {
        "leadId": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
        },
        "emailId": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.emailId')"
        },
        "responses": {
            "L": [            // List type
            #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.responses) // Loop thru array
                {
                    "M": {        // Map type
                        "answer": {
                            "S": "$elem.answer"
                        },
                        "question": {
                            "S": "$elem.question"
                        }
                    }
                }
                #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
            #end
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

**Integration Response Template** (similar structure as request)

```
#set($inputRoot = $input.path('$'))
{
  "$results": [
    #foreach($elem in $inputRoot.Items)
    {
      "emailId": "$elem.emailId.S",
      "responses": [
          #foreach($resp in $elem.responses.L)
          {
           "question": "$resp.M.question.S",
           "answer": "$resp.M.answer.S"
          }
          #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
          #end
      ]
    }
    #if($foreach.hasNext),#end
    #end
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you help point me to documentation for "S" = String, "L" = List, "M" = map? What about Integer/Number?

Comment: Ah it's not VTL/API Gateway but DynamoDB, makes sense. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html#DDB-Type-AttributeValue-M

Answer (score 5):

Your mapping template doesn't match the DynamoDB format. It should be something like,

```
{ 
    "TableName": "Comments",
    "Item": {
        "commentId": {
            "S": "$context.requestId"
        },
        "pageId": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.pageId')"
            },
        "userName": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.userName')"
        },
        "message": {
            "S": "$input.path('$.message')"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok ... I got your point ... but I want to add a Json Object into of the database field - can you provide a reference in aws docs for it.

Comment: It worked but I am trying to add a array of Json object as well - for which i am referring to http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/example-invoice.html#example-invoice-input-mapping  but I am not getting aws docs for API Datatypes

Comment: How can we access Header value in this template? Let's say we want to pass on "origin" header value to DynamoDB and store there..